# Subexponential algorithm for Np-complete problems

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/3627/32204

Could someone explain to me why this reasoning is false. I don't understand it! To me this sounds plausible!

Comment: It's in the answer?

Comment: Rather, in the last comment of http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/3627/32204.  The comment by @RussellImpagliazzo explains why the third bullet of the reasoning in the answer is incorrect.

Comment: yes i read that comment, but i don't understand the comment. That is the reason i asked the question.

Comment: The ETH is that any algorithm for 3SAT must be exponential.  If you can reduce 3SAT to NP problem X in polynomial time and space and then solve X, X must be NP complete.  But if the size $M$ 3SAT problem is transformed into a size $N=M^2$ X problem, then you could still solve X in time $2^\sqrt{N} = 2^M$ without violating the ETH.  Solving a size $M$ 3SAT problem still takes time $2^M$ (exponential), but solving an X problem takes time $2^\sqrt{N}$ (subexponential).

Comment: Now this makes sense! and what about 3SAT has no pseudo-poly-algorithm but there are NP-complete-problems which have one. Then 3SAT should also have one, since it is reduzible to one.(but it is false) i think there is a different reasoning for this false claim?

Comment: I can't think of any NP-complete problems with pseudo-poly algorithms.

Comment: what about the knapsack problem?